# How to push property in array with RXJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using angular with plotly and I am trying to push a specfic property countUp into a array with a api call.

And I have a model CameraNodeValueModel, that looks like this:

```
export interface CameraNodeValueModel {
  readonly id?: number;
  readonly dt?: string;
  readonly count_down?: number;
  readonly count_up?: number;
}
```

The api call looks like this:

```
showLineChart() {
    return this.sensorNodeService
      .cameraDataInInterval(16, '2021-01-19 00:00:00', '2021-01-19 23:59:59', '1')
      .pipe(
        map((data) =>
          data.map((obj) => {
            return obj;          
          })
        )
      );
  }
```

and I am using that in here:

```
 cameraNodevalue: Array<CameraNodeValueModel> = [];
this.showLineChart().subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.graph = {
        data: [
          {
            x: [
              '2021-01-19 12:50:00',
              '2021-01-19 13:51:00',
              '2021-01-19 14:52:00',
              '2021-01-19 15:53:00',
              '2021-01-19 16:54:00',
            ],
            y: [-10, -87, -30, -69, -50],
            stackgroup: 'one',
            fillcolor: '#F2A2A2',
            mode: 'none',
          },
          {
            x: [
              '2021-01-19 12:50:00',
              '2021-01-19 13:51:00',
              '2021-01-19 14:52:00',
              '2021-01-19 15:53:00',
              '2021-01-19 16:54:00',
            ],
            y: res.push(res.map(countUp => countUp.countUp)),
            stackgroup: 'two',
            fillcolor: '#F3CFCF',
            mode: 'none',
          },
        ],
        layout: {
          autosize: true,
          margin: {
            t: 15,
            r: 30,
            b: 30,
            l: 45,
          },
          xaxis: {
            range: this.xrange,
            showgrid: false,
            zeroline: true,
            showline: false,
            autotick: true,
            ticks: '',
            showticklabels: true,
          },
          yaxis: {
            range: this.yrange,
            showgrid: false,
            zeroline: true,
            showline: false,
            autotick: true,
            ticks: '',
            showticklabels: true,
          },
          showlegend: false,
        },
      };
    });
```

So I try to push the values countUp like this:

```
  y: res.push(res.map(countUp => countUp.countUp)),
```

But that doesnt work. So what I have to change?

Thank you

Comment: no need to use `push`, `map` return new array. =>  `y: res.map(countUp => countUp.countUp)`

Comment: `map(data => data.map(obj => obj)))` doesn't do anything but using CPU time. It maps `data` to `data` and `obj` to `obj`.